# Officer package - Error in absolute_path(target)

Tags: r

Within my function, if I run each line manually I can save normally in docx through the office package. However, when rotating the function the following error appears:

```
Error in absolute_path(target) : 'x' must be a single character string
Além disso: Warning messages:
1: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin). 
2: In if (!grepl(x = target, pattern = "\\.(docx)$", ignore.case = TRUE)) stop(target,  :

 Error in absolute_path(target) : 'x' must be a single character string
```

The warning message 1 I know where it is from, but I don't know how to handle this error.

I believe the error is in this part:

```
doc <- read_docx()
    doc<-doc %>%
      body_add_flextable(par) %>%
      body_add_par("", style = "Normal") %>% # blank paragraph
      body_add_par("", style = "Normal") %>% # blank paragraph
      body_add_flextable(vopa) %>%
      body_add_par("", style = "Normal") %>% # blank paragraph
      body_add_par("", style = "Normal") %>% # blank paragraph
      body_add_gg(diam) %>%
      body_add_par("", style = "Normal") %>% # blank paragraph
      body_add_par("", style = "Normal") %>% # blank paragraph
      body_add_flextable(vtt) %>%
      body_add_par("", style = "Normal") %>% # blank paragraph
      body_add_par("", style = "Normal") %>% # blank paragraph
      body_add_flextable(phi) %>%
      body_add_par("", style = "Normal") %>% # blank paragraph
      body_add_par("", style = "Normal") %>% # blank paragraph
      body_add_flextable(ft) %>%
      body_add_par("", style = "Normal") %>% # blank paragraph
      body_add_par("", style = "Normal") %>% # blank paragraph
      body_add_gg(gg) %>%
      body_add_par("", style = "Normal") %>% # blank paragraph
      body_add_par("", style = "Normal") %>% # blank paragraph
      body_add_gg(sa)
      end<-"end"

      }


  if(pt==T){
  fileout <- tempfile(fileext = ".docx")
  fileout <- paste(getwd(),"/Inventario Florestal - ",nm,".docx",sep="")
  print(doc, target = fileout)
  }else{
    fileout <- tempfile(fileext = ".docx")
    fileout <- paste(getwd(),"/Forest Inventory - ",nm,".docx",sep="")
  print(doc, target = fileout)

  }
```

Comment: Your code is not completely reproducible for us, that makes it a bit more difficult for us to see what's going on. Does your output folder exist? Why are you overwriting `fileout`?

Comment: Rico, Above this code just created the flextable and ggplot used. As for the fileout, when removing the replacement continues the error, but every time a different error appears ...

Comment: Cobel, if I run your code. It is missing a few things. I removed them. I tried with `pt` being `TRUE` and `FALSE`. I assumed `nm` is a number. In all cases the code worked for me. You also have a `}` in your code, just after `end <- "end"` so there is more. It doesn't belong to anything. From the error I would say, there is some kind of path which is empty.